# Remove "pp." (for page numbers) from bibliography in Natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I want to remove the letters preceding the page numbers, may it be "p" or "pp". I use natbib with bibliography style agsmso that this

```
@article{key,
  title={Title},
  author={Author},
  journal={Journal},
  pages={2--3},
}
```

renders this
Author, Title, Journal: 2-3

and not

Author, Title, Journal: pp. 2-3